# Swing get JTextField upon JButton press

Tags: java, swing

Apparently my Google-fu skills are bit lacklustre and I can't figure out how to get JTextField when pressing a JButton.

Please note that I've removed some parts of the code for ease of reading.

If you see some variable that's not defined assume that it was part of that code.

As it stands, the code works fine.

```
public final class Main {
    // Some removed code was here
    private void prepareGUI() {

        // Top right stuff
        JPanel topRightPanel = new JPanel();
        topRightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel topRightLabel = new JLabel("Address");
        JTextField topRightTextField = new JTextField("", 15);
        topRightTextField.setName("add_address");
        JButton topRightButton = new JButton("Add");
        topRightButton.setName("add_btn");

        topRightPanel.add(topRightLabel);
        topRightPanel.add(topRightTextField);
        topRightPanel.add(topRightButton);
        mainFrame.add(topRightPanel);

        // The button in question. Very suggestive name, I know.
        topRightButton.addActionListener(new GenericButtonListener());

        genericButtonListener.setKernel(kernel);

        // some other non relevant stuff here

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class GenericButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String btnName = btn.getName();

        if(btnName.toLowerCase().contains("add_btn")) {
            addBtn(btn);
        }
    }

    public void addBtn(JButton button){
        SshFileIO sshFileIO = kernel.getFileIO();
        // Get field text here
    }
}
```

My current dilemma is how to get said textfield value inside `GenericButtonListener`.

I realize that I can use [`getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) to get the text field value, however I don't have access to that variable inside the `actionPerformed` function.

I suppose this is more of a scoping problem rather than anything else.

I just need some pointing in the right direction, no hand holding required.

It's painfully obvious that I'm very new to Java.

Comment: What IDE and tools you are using for development?

Comment: Did you mean to do  `topRightButton.addActionListener(genericButtonListener)` ?

Comment: @Laxminarayan Intellij Idea CE as in IDE and as the tools go, just the ones that come with the IDE, haven't gotten too far into setting up any sort of decent environment.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @Andrei, if you use NetBeans it will give you more flexibility and to code it right. and `btnName.getText()` is a right way to get text field value. Maybe you are not getting the reference to the textField. Make it class level so you will get anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to get a reference of topRightTextField with the constructor of GenericButtonListener. Store as property of the class and use it inside actionPerformed.

Change this one:

```
 topRightButton.addActionListener(new GenericButtonListener());
```

To this:

```
 topRightButton.addActionListener(new GenericButtonListener(topRightTextField));
```

And inside class GenericButtonListener add field:

```
private JTextField topRightTextField;// set it in the constructor
```

And then use it inside of your method actionPerformed.

Have a nice coding and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using a container class with a hashmap for the various components. Same idea, just different execution, I guess I'll just accept your answer.